# How do I make a python turtle program wait a bit?

Tags: python, python-turtle

So I'm making a game where the two turtles race each other, but I want them to wait a bit before they start (to display a 3,2,1) screen. But I can't figure it out! I used time.sleep, and turtle.delay, but both did not work. What can I do? Here is the code :)

```
import turtle
import random
import time

turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt2 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.Screen() .bgcolor("green")

turt.speed(10)
turt.penup()
turt.goto(200,100)
turt.pendown()
turt.right(90)
turt.width(10)
turt.forward(450)
turt.right(180)
turt.forward(800)



#position 1
turt.penup()
turt.goto(-400,200)
turt.pendown()
turt.right(90)
turt.forward(100)



#position 2 
turt2.width(10)
turt2.penup()
turt2.goto(-400,-200)
turt2.pendown()
turt2.forward(100)
```

Comment: Well, `time.sleep` is exactly the right way to do that.  You'll do it just after you set the background color.

Comment: Tim Roberts it does not work :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " used time.sleep, and turtle.delay, but both did not work. " The code shown here does not use either of those things. We can only possibly explain problems with code that is actually shown to us; in particular, we can only explain what went wrong with an attempt to use `time.sleep` if we are shown that attempt. We also cannot possibly explain, under any circumstance, why something "did not work", because that does not mean anything. **What happened** when you tried the code? What was supposed to happen instead, and **how is that different**?

Comment: remember that time.sleep uses seconds (like "time.sleep(1)" for one second) and makes the code wait before running code after it, so you'll need to put it between each number(or whatever you'll use to indicate your countdown)

Comment: Do you understand that "it does not work" tells us absolutely nothing at all?  `time.sleep` definitely DOES work.  Did you put in a long delay so you could see the effect?

Comment: I don't know what more to say than it did not work :). It's kind of simple! I know details are important, but all I was saying was that when I put it after the bg color, it did not work, sense in that situation, it would not have been useful anyway. All im saying is it doesn't work there. Chill :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the advice so far, I'd avoid `sleep()` in my turtle program and use `ontimer()` instead to countdown the start of the race:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choice

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'bold')

def race():
    while turtle_1.xcor() < 200 > turtle_2.xcor():
        choice([turtle_1, turtle_2]).forward(10)

def countdown(seconds=3):
    pen.clear()

    if seconds < 1:
        screen.ontimer(race)
    else:
        pen.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)
        screen.ontimer(lambda: countdown(seconds - 1), 1000)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('green')

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.speed('fastest')
marker.color('white')
marker.width(5)

marker.penup()
marker.goto(200, 300)
marker.pendown()

marker.right(90)
marker.forward(600)

pen = Turtle()
pen.hideturtle()

turtle_1 = Turtle()
turtle_1.shape('turtle')
turtle_1.color('red')
turtle_1.penup()
turtle_1.goto(-400, 200)

turtle_2 = turtle_1.clone()
turtle_1.color('blue')
turtle_2.goto(-400, -200)

countdown()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Be careful if we removed "lambda:" from ontimer call, the second argument 1000 was ignored.

Comment: @GoldenThumb, if you remove the `lambda:` there's no point to the `ontimer()` call as the first argument is executed immediately and `None` is passed into the function.  I don't see your point.  If we leave off the `countdown(...)`, nothing happens.  If we leave off the `screen.` it's a syntax error. Etc.